# GooglePlay publishing app report: Native crash of com.myapp.app

Tags: android, flutter, crash, google-play

Hi friends I uploaded my app to GooglePlay Console for internal testing, I got this strange report for a low-level device :( that app crashed, can you please help me with this issue to understand exactly what is wrong :( thanks in advance!

**Error**

```
    *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'generic/gce_x86_phone/gce_x86:9/PGR1.190916.001/5877764:userdebug/test-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 6928, tid: 8107, name: 1.raster  >>> com.rainpixels.unipeople <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'vendor/unbundled_google/libs/ndk_translation/ndk_translation/ir/include/ndk_translation/ir/ir.h:685: CHECK failed: IsAligned(offset, GetFormatSize(format))'
    eax 00000000  ebx 00001b10  ecx 00001fab  edx 00000006
    edi 00001b10  esi cbd86b5c
    ebp cbd86b28  esp cbd86ab8  eip f6819be9
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000be9  [vdso:f6819000] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
    #01 pc 0001fdf8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
    #02 pc 00022e73  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+115)
    #03 pc 00006c84  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+292)
    #04 pc 0009f2b4  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::GetInsn::GetInsn(ndk_translation::IR*, ndk_translation::Format, unsigned int)+276)
    #05 pc 0009f100  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::IRBuilder::Get(ndk_translation::Format, unsigned int)+144)
    #06 pc 0009dd2e  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::(anonymous namespace)::InsnBuilder::Get(ndk_translation::Format, unsigned int)+46)
    #07 pc 000d0b4b  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::SemanticsDecoder::VTBL(ndk_translation::VTBL_Args const&)+363)
    #08 pc 00100568  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::ArmDecoder::TranslateThumbInsn(unsigned short const*)+86104)
    #09 pc 0009c2b6  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::(anonymous namespace)::GenerateIRHelper(ndk_translation::CompilerHooks*, unsigned int, unsigned int, ndk_translation::IR*)+1142)
    #10 pc 0009be1f  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::GenerateIR(ndk_translation::CompilerHooks*, unsigned int, ndk_translation::IR*, unsigned int*)+47)
    #11 pc 0009bbdf  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::Compile(ndk_translation::CompilerHooks*, unsigned int, ndk_translation::GuestCodeEntry*, unsigned int*, ndk_translation::MachineCode*)+143)
    #12 pc 0007a0da  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::(anonymous namespace)::Translate(ndk_translation::TranslationCache*, unsigned int, ndk_translation::GuestCodeEntry*)+378)
    #13 pc 00079f1c  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation_HandleNotTranslated+300)
    #14 pc 0018db57  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@DorinBuraca I think that you are trying to run the app on an **unsupported api level**.
You should follow this step to check:

1. Try running that same functionality in other higher api device, if it works on a device with higher api level(preferably > 26) then your app's minimum sdk version is wrong. You are using a functionality which is not supported on such lower api levels.
   For eg: If you try to use speech to text on api level lower than 21 then it will throw an error.